# React Component sends [object Object] in request query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest

I am building a SWAPI app with React and Typescript and my goal is to be able to get information on a specific person when I click on link. My current issue, is that when I try to get data from the api, with the code fragment shown below, I see that instead of passing the id, I am sending [object Object]

```
const CharacterDetails = (id): JSX.Element => {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState<any | null>([]);

  const handleCharacterRequest = async (id) => {
    try {
      const results = await getCharacter(id);
      setCharacter(results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCharacterRequest(id)
  }, [])
```

However, when I hardcode in the id i want to send, as shown below in the code, the request works fine

```
const CharacterDetails = (id): JSX.Element => {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState<any | null>([]);

  const handleCharacterRequest = async (id) => {
    try {
      const results = await getCharacter(id);
      setCharacter(results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCharacterRequest(1)
  }, [])
```

The component should be able to receive the ID from the home page, when I click on the entry from the table, by using react-router-dom navigate method:

```
  const clickHandler = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { id } = event.target as HTMLElement;
    navigate(`/character/${id}`);
  };
```

And clicking on this table entry:

```
<TableCell id={character.id} onClick={(event: any) => clickHandler(event)}>
Id: {character.id}
</TableCell>
```

What am I missing? Am I setting the wrong parameters?

EDIT: Here is how React Router passes the id for the component, perhaps something here is missing?

```
<Route path='/character/:id' element={<CharacterDetails />}/>
```

Comment: You should check (log or debug) what really is passed into your `clickHandler`... I assume it's not actually a number.

Comment: Ideally, it should be passed as a string, since I am getting the ID as a string from response object of API

Comment: On a side note, instead of reading the ID for the element (and it should be `event.currentTarget` if you want to be precise), why not simply pass the character.id directly to the function? In fact, you can just call navigate directly, i.e. `onClick={() => navigate(\`/character/${character.id}\`)}`

Comment: One code optimization i did, was to get rid of the onClick event and pass in a <Link> component from react-router-dom, like this: `<Link to={`/character/${character.id}`}>More details</Link>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. In my code, I needed to use the `useParams()` method from react-router-dom.

So the solution looks like this:

```
const CharacterDetails = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState<any | null>([]);

  const { id } = useParams();

  const handleCharacterRequest = async (id) => {
    try {
      const results = await getCharacter(id);
      setCharacter(results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id)
    handleCharacterRequest(id)
  }, [])
```